# See outgoing headers before request sent to server

Tags: android, http-headers

I want to see my outgoing headers before my request goes to server. I am able to catch incoming headers from server but now i want to see what my webView is sending with HTTP request.

Is there any way to catch them?

Comment: have tried this method httppost.getAllHeaders()?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia...it will get all incoming headers in this way. I want to see the outgoing headers with the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got request headers from this [Link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hc-httpclient-users/201010.mbox/%3C20101024230004.314760@gmx.net%3E).